# only allow one object to be dropped jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

```
$("li").draggable({
            helper: "clone"
        });

        $("#div1").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                $("<p></p>").appendTo("#div1");

            }
        });
```

I have objects in a list that can be dragged and dropped into a div named div1. But when I drop one into the div i don't want to be able to drop another into it. I have tried using, for, if and while loops with a count.

Comment: A suggestion: perhaps you could make use of jQuery's .one() event handler (http://api.jquery.com/one/). Description: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full solution, it allows only one item dropped, but also, if one exists, it gets replaced on the next drop with the new one. (Usefull if someone changes their mind.  Just call

```
refreshDragDrop(dragClassName,dropDivId); 

refreshDragDrop = function(dragClassName,dropDivId) {
  $( "." + dragClassName ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#" + dropDivId,
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#" + dropDivId).droppable({
    accept: '.' + dragClassName,
    drop: function (event, ui) {
      var $this = $(this),
        maxItemsCount = 1;
      if ($this.children('div').length == maxItemsCount ){
        //more than one item,just replace
        $(this).html($(ui.draggable).clone());
      } else {
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
    var $this = $(this),
    maxItemsCount = 1;

    if ($this.children('li').length > maxItemsCount ){
        ui.sender.draggable('cancel');
        alert("To much items!");                
    }    

}
```

Comment: using this i cannot get it to append to div, i tried puttin in append aswell